# Crash after returning to tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, memory-management

So I am writing an app to read an rss feed, and display the contents in a tableview. It also lets the user play back mp3s that it finds for each item. Anyway the app seemed to be running fine before I started adding new views. Now every time I come back from a view and scroll around a bit, I get "Program received signal "SIGABRT"" or something similar.

here's most of the program:

```
- (IBAction)playAction:(id)sender
{
// Get row
UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
UITableViewCell *buttonCell = 
(UITableViewCell *) [[senderButton superview] superview];
NSInteger buttonRow = [[self.tableView 
                        indexPathForCell:buttonCell] row];

// Entry for row
RSSEntry *senderEntry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:buttonRow];


// This is where _allEntries gets filled

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

[_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]
                                                           options:0 error:&error];

    if (doc == nil) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to parse %@", request.url);
    } 
    else 
    {

        NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self parseRss:doc.rootElement entries:entries]; 

        if ([_allEntries count] > 0) {

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                // Update
                int i=0;
                while (![[[_allEntries objectAtIndex:i] articleUrl] isEqualToString:[[entries objectAtIndex:i] articleUrl]]) 
                {
                    [_allEntries insertObject:[entries objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:0];
                    i++;
                }
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }];

        }
        else
        {
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                for (RSSEntry *entry in entries)
                {
                    [_allEntries addObject:entry];
                }

                NSLog(@"entries:%d", [_allEntries count]);
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }];
        }


    }

}];



}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"View did load");

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh 
                                          target:self 
                                          action:@selector(refreshButton:)];

pauseImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pause_circle_small.png"];
playImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play_circle_small.png"];

player = nil;
isPlaying = NO;

self.title = @"Feed";
self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
self.queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
self.feed = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://site.org/rss/"];
[self refresh];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [_allEntries count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UILabel *mainLabel, *secondLabel;
UIButton *playBtn;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42.0, 5.0, 250.0, 20.0)] autorelease];
    mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
    mainLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18.0];
    mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    mainLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

    secondLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42.0, 27.0, 250.0, 15.0)] autorelease];
    secondLabel.tag = SECONDLABEL_TAG;
    secondLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14.0];
    secondLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:222.0/255.0 green:95.0/255.0 
                                             blue:199.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    secondLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

    playBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    playBtn.tag = PLAYBTN_TAG;
    playBtn.frame = CGRectMake(2.0, 6.0, playImage.size.width, playImage.size.height);
    [playBtn setBackgroundImage:playImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[playBtn setBackgroundImage:playImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playTapped:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:playBtn];
}
else 
{
    mainLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MAINLABEL_TAG];
    secondLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:SECONDLABEL_TAG];
    playBtn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PLAYBTN_TAG];
}

// Alternate bg color
if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
    UIColor *altColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0
                                         blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    mainLabel.backgroundColor = altColor;
    secondLabel.backgroundColor = altColor;
}
else
{
    UIColor *altColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0
                                         blue:255.0 alpha:1];
    mainLabel.backgroundColor = altColor;
    secondLabel.backgroundColor = altColor;
}

RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Entry: %@", entry);

// Manage play button
if (entry == currEntry)
{
    if(isPlaying)
    {
        [playBtn setBackgroundImage:pauseImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [playBtn  setBackgroundImage:playImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
else
    [playBtn setBackgroundImage:playImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

mainLabel.text = entry.articleTitle;
secondLabel.text = entry.articleArtist;

return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

DetailView *detailViewController = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];



[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

detailViewController.songTitle.text = entry.articleTitle;
detailViewController.artistName.text = entry.articleArtist;

[entry release];

[detailViewController release];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
[player release];
player = nil;
[_queue release];
_queue = nil;
[_feed release];
_feed = nil;
[_allEntries release];
_allEntries = nil;

[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Do not release iVar in your `viewDidLoad:`, you should do it in `delloc` method instead. Remove this: `[self.feed release];`. I cannot make sure it'll solve your problem. :)

Comment: So when it does crash on `mainLabel.text = entry.articleTitle`, it does in fact point to a bad address. I just don't know how my RSSEntry object is getting changed.

Comment: Are you sure the bad address is on `entry` not `mainLabel`?

Comment: In the light of @Eiko's answer, I found that your `pauseImage` & `playImage` are iVar! They'll be autoreleased when out the method, just follow @Eiko's suggestion. ;)

Comment: @Kjuly Yeah I fixed that. For some reason my `articleTitle` or `articleArtist` are nil when it crashes. They shouldn't be changing at all.

Comment: I would like to see how your `_allEntries` was initiated. Can you post your code snippet about it?

Comment: Ok I'll try to post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Please Dont release any @synthesize variable. You should only release it in dealloc method

Comment: Good call, but I fixed it and it's still the same situation. Anytime I leave the tableview and come back it crashes.

Comment: I'm sure you releasing some variable that you should not. Try to use NSAutoreleasePool for all varables.

Answer (score 1):

It's a wild guess, but you don't retain the images that you get in `viewDidLoad`:

```
pauseImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pause_circle_small.png"];
playImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play_circle_small.png"];
```

Either use retaining  property and dot syntax or send each a `retain`.

Comment: Ahh I wasn't using a retain there, so yeah I fixed that. Still crashing though.

Comment: If it's crashing on the mainLabel.text = ... line, set a breakpoint before that line and check both the label and the entry.

Answer (score 1):

AHAA!!! I was setting my RSSEntry to autorelease before putting them in the _allEntries array. They were getting dealloc'd when I changed views. Don't do that. Thanks for the help everyone. That was so simple, I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 0):

please don't release the self.feed and also when unload or dealloc the view at that time put delegate nil means

tableview.delegate = nil;

this one is the main thing check after this i think u don't nil the delegate of tableview.

Comment: You mean that in the -dealloc method I should be releasing the delegate? Did not know that. But dealloc isn't called till the very end of the program.

Answer (score -1):

without line where you get crash its hard to tell, but most likely you accessing some object what was dealloc'ed

most likely its here

```
self.feed = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://site.org/rss/music"];
[self.feed release];
```

you releasing objects right away, but its hard to tell without knowing if you have retained property

Comment: Sometimes it crashes on the line "mainLabel.text = entry.articleTitle;"

Comment: It's hard to see that the RSSEntry would be getting dealloc'd though, I'm not deallocing anything when the view switches. I don't think so anyway...

Comment: Not a good pattern but most probably ok here if feed is a 'retain'ed  property. (Which we cannot know but should expect)